# Rspec for ability model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.type == 'ABCD' && user.type_sec == 'ADMIN'
      can :manage, Data
      can :manage, Bills
      can :manage, Cash
      can :manage, Booklets
    elsif user.type == 'ABCD' && user.type_sec == 'USER' then
      can :manage, Data
      can :manage, Bills
    end
  end 
end
```

this is my ability model, i am looking for the rspec for this model and i tried

```
context "abcd admin" do
  let(:user) { create :user, :abcd_admin }
  it "can manage" do
    initialize(user)
    user.can?(:manage, Data).should be_true
    user.can?(:manage, Bills).should be_true
    user.can?(:manage, Cash).should be_true
    user.can?(:manage, Booklets).should be_true
  end
end
```

But the test cases getting failed, any answer will be appreciable, thanks in advance.

The ERROR i got
    Failure/Error: let(:user) { create :user, :abcd_admin }

```
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Email has already been taken
```

Comment: You don't clean your database between tests?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i Cleaned my test database before i start testing.

Comment: Yes, you also need to clean it before each test case, so that data from previously executed tests don't affect your current one.

Comment: yes, i did.. but i again and again am getting the same error. @SergioTulentsev

Comment: How you did that?

Comment: https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner

Comment: The mock email in the factory is now not in the test database, i removed it and run the spec

Comment: can you post your factory bot creation code? perhaps you are creating other users (which have the same email address)? try using an faker gem to substitute many random email addresses everytime a user is created.